# How to use Partial View Model in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have a controller named `DaftarController` that calls Index view and fill it with mode.l

DaftarController:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<EventRecord> li = ws.GetEvents().ToList();
        var ura = li;
        return View(ura);
    }
```

It shows perfectly, but I want partial view inside my Index view.

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Daftar/_Deleted.cshtml");
```

So I add this in my DaftarController:

```
    public ActionResult _Deleted()
    {
        List<DeletedRecord> li = ws.GetDeleteds().ToList();
        var ura = li;
        return View(ura);
    }
```

But it gives error. I'm still confuse how to show partial view with model in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call an action even though the action will return a partial view, you should use.

```
@Html.Action("_Deleted", "Daftar") // Assume _Deleted is inside DaftarController
```

This will call the action then returns the view, and in your `_Deleted` action, you need to return it with `PartialView` method otherwise the layout will be included as the result.

```
public ActionResult _Deleted()
{
    List<DeletedRecord> li = ws.GetDeleteds().ToList();
    var ura = li;
    return PartialView(ura); // Not View(ura)
}
```

If you directly call the`@Html.PartialView`, that means you directly render the view without going to the action.

Answer (score 2):

When you are defining a partial view to use in a razor view, you do not define the path with the file extension.

So for your partial, it would be:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Daftar/_Deleted");
```

Comment: Nope, without .cshtml extension it return error View not found